# Can we use Angular.js as a complete replacement for a javascript template engine?

Tags: angularjs, javascript, template-engine

Although angular is best fit for two way data binding and single page applications but can we see it as replacement for a javascript template engine ? What can be the pros and cons ?

Comment: Angular.js compiles on browser (client side ) and there are server side javascript template engines also. Can this factor also make difference in some cases ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AngularJS` is much more than a template engine. It is a framework and consider it as such. A framework enforces you to think in a certain way. Do not embrace `AngularJS` if your main interest is to take advantage of templating capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

As a framework , angular certainly has powerful template capabilities above and beyond most other scripts that focus solely on client side templates.

Would it be considered a replacement such that other template scripts won't be needed again? No.

You won't need other template engines within angular pages but that doesn't mean someone that only needs a template engine should switch to angular solely for one feature that a lighter package can deliver.

Comment: Angular.js compiles on browser (client side ) and there are server side javascript template engines also. Can this factor also make difference in some cases ???

Comment: difference in what? Server side and client side have different purposes. Consider mean.js it uses some simple SWIG templates to send the initial page for angular to use